# responsive div container in height in mobile devices and large screen fixed the container height

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am just novice and I want to know how to make responsive div container in height on mobile devices and large screens and fix the container's height?

```
 @media all and (max-width: 1000px)
       {
           div.shw
           {height: 900px;
           }
       }

<div class="container-fluid" style="height:650px" class="shw">
  <div class="row" >
        <div  class="col-sm-12 "align="center"class="custom" style="color:#069; font-size: 14px" > ....</div>
        <div  class="col-sm-12 " class="col-md-12" style="text-align:justify;   font-size: 14px; color:#069;"class="custom" >
      </div>
<?php }?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, please clarify. What is "in height on mobile"

Comment: i want to div in responsive

Comment: actually i want to design a menu list that area of show in menu is fixed in height of the large scren but is same thing run on the mobile or other small device the div is inresponsive